# forcepae lubuntu instructions do not work

Tags: lubuntu, pae

I am trying to folow the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE but cant get it working.  It says 'When the image of a keyboard and a little man in a circle appears, hit the tab key.' but I dont see the image of a keyboard or little man, it just goes stright into asking me to select language.  Ive tried tapping tab during boot up but no joy;(.

Comment: I grabbed a lubuntu and tried booting on an old laptop & I didn't get the man-circle either. I got language, then the menu, where I could go to install, hit <e> or <f6> ('e' to edit is habit; it says f6 on screen) and it let me edit the linux (kernel) options allowing `forcepae --forcepae` to be added.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Lubuntu you tried installing?  It was 16.04 on the image I tried/used.

Comment: 16.4.  I tried adding 'forcepae -- forcepae after flash and still get the error.  I says cx8 as well as pae is not present;(.

Comment: Still gives the same error.

Comment: you've added it twice; once with '--', once without, ie. added ` forcepae --forcepae` as per the instructions?

Comment: tried tried '..splash forcepae --forepae' and '..splash forcepae -- forepae' and neither work.  The instructions actually have space after --.

Comment: well you just taught me something (so thanks!), and doco is correct (you need the space!).  Can you please try again removing the "quiet splash" and adding "forcepae -- forcepae" (at the end of the [linux] line) to get the error message & provide it for me (either edit your question & put there (you have more control on question) or comment it back (even last few lines being accurate on last please)

Answer (score 2):

My laptop is a Dell d600. I upgraded the ram to 1.25 Gbytes.
Here's how I installed Lubuntu:

1. Boot from DVD Lubuntu 16.04 LTS
2. Choose your language within 30 sec when it pop up.
3. Highlight "install Lubuntu".
4. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>.
5. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
   (at bottom, a row appears, it says:
   boot options: ........... quiet splash.)
6. Use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> of your keyboard to erase "quiet splash" and type in "forcepae", then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Wait about 30 sec.
   The screen turns to:

   > Warning: forcing PAE in CPU flags.

   Then the laptop starts the installation.

Comment: Here is the reference: https://docs.lubuntu.net/lubuntu_installation_on_old_computers

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with the erase of "quiet splash"and write"forcepae" .
solved
PF6 and add after "quiet splash"space "forcepae" space-- and enter Ubuntu will be installed properly.